# Update column for random value from different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update TableA.columnA with a random value from TableB.columnB. Business case: I have thousands of clients contracts in TableA and I need to assign them Random sales representative who are in TableB

If i use `select * from tableb order by dbms_random.random`, it sets columnA 1 random value only, but i need all 11

Oracle 11.2+

Comment: Oracle (at least through 11.2) doesn't accept the `TOP n` syntax. What version of Oracle are you using? In addition, I don't believe you can order by `DBMS_RANDOM`, which is the name of a package.  (I'm guessing that `dmbms_random` was a typo). You might be thinking of `DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Oracle 11.2+, yes jsut to type it faster, but you got the idea

Comment: If you want help it's really necessary to post code which will execute. Please edit your post and include a working query. Thanks.

Comment: I need to update TableA.columnA with a random value from TableB.columnB. Business case: I have thousands of clients contracts in TableA and I need to assign them Random sales representative who are in TableB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() (since RANDOM is deprecated) and generate a value between 1 and the rowcount of TableB. Then, do this:

```
select * from (
    select b.*, b_rownum=rownum from TableB b where rownum <= <your_random_rownum>
) where b_rownum = <your_random_rownum>
```

to get your one random row from TableB